# Using Multiple Descendants in the same crossjoin

Tags: mdx

I'm  trying to use multiple members within the same dimension (in the same crossjoin) to have level 0 descendants.

I'd like it to be somehting like this:

```
Crossjoin(
   {Descendants(
       [LB_PL_HOME],[LOB].levels(0)
    )
   ,Descendants(
       [LB_PL_OTH],[LOB].levels(0)
    )
   },
```

Only I can't get the syntax to work.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work:

```
Descendants(
   [LB_PL_HOME]
  ,[LOB].levels(0)
)
```

Well I assume it won't work as it doesn't look like `[LB_PL_HOME]` and `[LOB]` are related - you're only allowed to find members at a specified level for a member within the same dimension. e.g. for a specified Year I would be allowed to find the members at the Day level, as Year and Day are related.

If `[LB_PL_HOME]` and `[LOB]` are from different dimensions then you could do something like this:

```
NonEmpty(
   [LOB].levels(0).MEMBERS
  ,[LB_PL_HOME]
)
```

Your next problem is that you're not allowed to crossjoin members from the same hierarchy but you could chuck them all into the same set:

```
{
  NonEmpty(
     [LOB].levels(0).MEMBERS
    ,[LB_PL_HOME]
  )
  ,NonEmpty(
     [LOB].levels(0).MEMBERS
    ,[LB_PL_OTH]
  )
}
```